# Pass data from one controller to another before close stage JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFx project with two stages. The main stage has the ability to launch second stage .In second stage I have a textfield I want to put some data into textfield and send it to the main stage and set it as a label .Here is my code:
**MAIN:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
     Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml")); 
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MAIN CONTROLLER:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.Button kbutton;
    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.Button obutton;
    @FXML
   public Label label;
    public TextField popField;
    @FXML
    public String text;

    @FXML
    private void konfButton()  throws Exception{
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/konfview.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();




            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
       public void myFunction( String text){
        popField.setText(text);    
    }

    @FXML
    private void oblButton() throws Exception{
        try {
        // get a handle to the stage
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();   
        Controller Controller=fxmlLoader.getController(); 
        Stage stage = (Stage) obutton.getScene().getWindow();  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
```

**MAIN FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="69.0" layoutY="81.0" text="previous reading" />
            <Label layoutX="69.0" layoutY="115.0" text="current reading" />
            <Label layoutX="71.0" layoutY="154.0" text="months" />
            <Label layoutX="108.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Price">

               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="97.0" layoutY="51.0" text="Give details">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button fx:id="kbutton" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="197.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#konfButton" text="Configure" />
            <Button fx:id="obutton" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="197.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#oblButton" text="OK" />
            <TextField fx:id="popField" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="77.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="bieField" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="111.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="mcField" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="150.0" />
            <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="245.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="333.0" text="text" />
         </children>

      </Pane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**SECOND CONTROLLER:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ControllerConf {

    @FXML
    public TextField palField;
    public Label label;
    public String text;
    @FXML
    private TextField dysField1;


    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.Button cancelB;
    @FXML
    public javafx.scene.control.Button saveB;

    @FXML
    private void cancelButton(){
        // get a handle to the stage
        Stage stage = (Stage) cancelB.getScene().getWindow();
        // do what you have to do
        stage.close();
    }

   @FXML
   public Stage saveButton(){

       try {

           FXMLLoader loader=new 
          FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
           Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
           Controller Controller=loader.getController();
           Controller.myFunction(palField.getText());
           Stage primaryStage = (Stage) saveB.getScene().getWindow();
           primaryStage.close();
      return primaryStage;

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return null;
       }
}
```

**SECOND FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.ControllerConf">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="185.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="314.0" text="Give details">
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="48.0" layoutY="95.0" text="Price pre KWh" />
      <Label layoutX="48.0" layoutY="135.0" text="Price pre item" />
      <TextField fx:id="palField" layoutX="252.0" layoutY="91.0" onAction="#saveButton" />
      <TextField fx:id="dysField" layoutX="252.0" layoutY="131.0" />
      <Button fx:id="cancelB" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="208.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelButton" text="Cancel">
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="saveB" layoutX="292.0" layoutY="209.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveButton" text="Save">
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I created MyFunction wchich set text and it's working fine when created new stage but doesnt for main stage.Do you know how to solve it?Thanks in advance.enter code here

Comment: A [`javafx.scene.control.Dialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) or a [`javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) might be better for your use case rather than another `Stage`. A `Dialog<R>` has the `showAndWait()` method which returns an `Optional<R>`. You can customize what is returned by the `Dialog`, as is described in the Javadoc.

Comment: Thank you Slaw for a quick response,a Dialog works for me as you mentioned,but  I'm still curious if it is possible to send variables between stages just using setters and getters as I mentioned above.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you are using FXML you can get the controller using `fxmlLoaderInstance.getController()`. Then you can set and get things by communicating with the controller. Make sure you only call `getController()` after a call to `fxmlLoaderInstance.load()`. There are many questions and answers on this site about communicating between controllers.